# How to convert UTC timestamp string to pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe with a column with date format as below:

```
PublishDateTime= 2018-08-31 12:00:00-UTC
```

I used panda to_gbq() function to dump data into a bigquery table. Before dumping data, I make sure that the format of columns match with table scheme. publishedate is timestamp in bigquery table. How can achieve something similar to:

```
df['PublishDateTime'] = df['PublishDateTime'].astype('?????')
```

I tried `datetime[ns]` but that didn't work!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main challenge in the conversion here is the format of your datetime. Pass `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z"` as an argument to `pd.to_datetime` and convert your column to `datetime`.

```
df['PublishDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PublishDateTime'], 
                                       format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z', 
                                       errors='coerce')
```

Comment: @MT467 yes it will, thanks to the errors="coerce" arg.

Comment: great! one more question, how can I convert this string to date("2018-08-31") so the data type be Date instead of timestamp in bigquery table?

Comment: @MT467 you can use df[...] = pd.to_datetime(...).date

Comment: I got this error :AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @MT467 ah sorry, it's .dt.date

Comment: tnx doesn't show error but the column became string instead of date. any idea?

Comment: @MT467 ah, drawing a blank here. Not at my computer, you may need to wait some time or open a new question.

Comment: it was working but suddenly I got this error today:  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 469, in to_datetime /NotImplementedError

Comment: @MT467 Are you using a different computer? Please make sure the versions are right. You may need to use a more recent version of python or pandas.